# For each statement decide whether it is true or false (justify your answer)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- For each statement decide whether it is true or false (justify your answer)

  1) $\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : x^{3}-2x=0\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$

False: Because $x^3-2x = 0 \implies x(x^2-2) = 0 \implies x = 0\ \lor\ x = \pm\sqrt2$.

$$\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : x^{3}-2x=0\} = \{0,-\sqrt2,\sqrt2\}$$

but $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

2) $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$

True: Since $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, for any $x\in \mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ and for any $y\in\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we have $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$.

3) $\{ (x,y) : x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x-1=0\} \subseteq  \{(x,y) : x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and  $x^{2}-1=0\}$

True: In the left hand side: soulition of $x-1=0$ is $x=1$. In the right hand side is $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Hence have

$$\left\{ (1,y) : y\in \mathbb{R}\right\} \subseteq  \left\{(1,y),(-1,y) :y\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

Can you check my answers? Thankss..

Comment: Okay, but justifying means explaining *why* your answer is yes.  Justify your answer.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Okey, I'm editing

Comment: @GrahamKemp Now, can you check?

Comment: Your new answers are correct.

Comment: @Grahamkemp Thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For second one and the third one, I think your answer is correct (You didn't write your justification but we can find surjection from RHS of $\subseteq$ to LHS). For the first one, I think it is not correct because note that $x^3-2x = 0 \implies x(x^2-2) = 0 \implies x = 0\ \lor\ x = \pm\sqrt2$.

$$\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : x^{3}-2x=0\} = \{0,-\sqrt2,\sqrt2\}$$

but $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer.